# TextView setContentDescription not working

Tags: java, android, textview, accessibility

I'm trying to set the `contentDescription` on a `TextView` but it doesn't seem to be announced by TalkBack. TalkBack is only vocalizing the text content.

```
textView.setText("2d 9h left");
textView.setContentDescription("2days 9hours left");
```

The second line above has no effect. TalkBack says, "2d 9h left".

I've also tried the following:

```
    ViewCompat.setAccessibilityDelegate(textView, new AccessibilityDelegateCompat()
    {
        @Override
        public void onPopulateAccessibilityEvent(View host, AccessibilityEvent event)
        {
            super.onPopulateAccessibilityEvent(host, event);
            event.getText().add(host.getContentDescription());
        }
    });
```

but this results in TalkBack announcing "2days 9hours left 2d 9h left", which is also incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only that worked for me is AccessibilityDelegate (Kotlin):

```
val accessibilityDelegate: View.AccessibilityDelegate =
            object : View.AccessibilityDelegate() {
                override fun onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(v: View?, info: AccessibilityNodeInfo) {
                    super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(v, info)
                    info.text = "Custom Text"
                }
            }
myView.accessibilityDelegate = accessibilityDelegate
```

Answer (score 2):

As per my knowledge, the `contentDescription` is applicable only for the views having to textual descriptions. For example, an `ImageView` might have a `contentDescription` with which the accessibility talkback feature might know what is the content of that view element when touched.

I am quoting from [this link](https://www.deque.com/blog/android-imageviews-accessible-content-descriptions/).

> The content description attribute links a text description to a
>   control, ImageView, or other focusable objects that otherwise has no
>   text content.

Hence, the talkback function should only vocalize the text that is written in your `TextView`.

In your case, you might consider having a work-around. Get an `ImageView` and set the `contentDescription` to that. The `ImageView` should have the same size as the `TextView` and should be placed over the `TextView`. Hence, when the `ImageView` is clicked, you can hear the desired `contentDescription` as specified in your program. The `ImageView` can have a transparent background or might be put `invisible`. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

There are chances that the text of the textView is being updated in other method/at other point after setting the contentDescription.
Have you installed the latest version of Talkback?
Also, You will have to set the contentdescription everywhere you are setting this text.
Please let me know if any more help is required.
If you want, then I'll help you with code also
And yes, the contentdescription can be applied to any view no matter what is it. so please don't use image view if not needed.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to MorZa for the answer. i think it is the most relevant and must be at the top. here is yet another variant i tried (it works but is more complicated):

```
class AccessibilityTextView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : AppCompatTextView(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    var customContentDescription: CharSequence = ""

    @SuppressLint("GetContentDescriptionOverride")
    override fun getContentDescription() = customContentDescription
}
```

usage:

```
myTextView.text = "$5-$20"
myTextView.customContentDescription = "From $5 to $20"
```